# How to configure karma to use 'define' (with backbone.js) properly?

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, jasmine, karma-runner, webstorm

I've installed karma. I've created a karma.conf.js file and pointed to my source files. In my source files is included a version of require.js.

Everything seems fine (it launches the node server, and Webstorm CLI connects to it properly) except it barfs when loading backbone style files that begin with `define(...` In my output I get

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
at http://localhost:9876/base/src/main/app/App.js?f2880b74f1e96a210ff36e8394daa946c9d11294:1
```

When I jump to code, the line indicated is just `define(` at the top of a backbone js file.

I've tried explicitly including require in my lib directory (which should have already been included from the wildcard)

Do I need some boilerplate somewhere to not muddle (possibly conflicting) require.js's? I tried ignoring require... but the result was the same.

```
 exclude: [
      '**/*.scss',
      '**/*.css',
      '**/Gruntfile.js',
        '**/docs/*.js',
        '**/main/resources/js/lib/crypto-js-3.1.2/*.js',
        '**/main/resources/js/lib/require-2.1.2.min.js' // same error when ignored
    ],
```

Only mildly related: I'm running karma from webstorm.

Comment: Couple of months back I had a hard time configuring it so I wrote a [blog post](http://puigcerber.wordpress.com/2013/12/23/using-grunt-to-run-mocha-tests-with-backbone-js-and-requirejs/) about it. I don't know but it may help you. I use WebStorm as well so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: hm. I wasn't planning on using grunt-karma. I guess i could, then it should just read my gruntfile. But the core of the question here is how to do it with Karma and karma-coverage (to be nicely integrated with WS), so i'm leaving it that way in case this is helpful to others. I supposed if i went the grunt way, i'd also use phantomjs and skip the browser altogether.

Comment: Sorry about that, as I'm currently working with AngularJS, I have misread completely that you want to use Karma with Backbone.js.

Comment: what does your karma confiog look like? Have you configured Require.js for tests like it's described in http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/plus/RequireJS.html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have to include 'requirejs' in your frameworks.  Make sure you include the requirejs string before others, ie:

```
    frameworks: ['requirejs','jasmine']
```